# Unable to get GitLab running on port 80 with Apache and Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.4, gitlab

I installed GitLab using the Omnibus installer.  It is currently working correctly using Nginx (which GitLab is bundled with) running on port 81.  I changed from port 80 to port 81 because I have Apache running on port 80.  I also have Tomcat installed and running on port 8080, so I changed the Unicorn port to 8081.  All of this works correctly.  Below are the settings I changed:

**/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**

```
# https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/629def0a7a26e7c2326566f0758d4a27857b52a3/README.md#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab
external_url 'http://mysite.example.net:81'

#https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#tcp-ports-for-gitlab-services-are-already-taken
unicorn['port'] = 8081

#https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#storing-git-data-in-an-alternative-directory
git_data_dir "/mnt/tank/gitlab"
```

**/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml**

```
production: &base
  #
  # 1. GitLab app settings
  # ==========================

  ## GitLab settings
  gitlab:
    ## Web server settings (note: host is the FQDN, do not include http://)
    host: mysite.example.net
    port: 81
    https: false
```

Unfortunately I need GitLab to run on port 80.  I have tried several Apache virtual host configurations.  The only success I have had is that I can type the URL `http://mysite.example.com/gitlab` and get a 404 error, but I see that the URL changes to `http://mysite.example.com/users/sign_in`.  The redirect caused the `gitlab` to be removed but if I put it back in to get the URL `http://mysite.example.com/gitlab/users/sign_in` I can see the GitLab login page, though it is all jacked up because none of the images are are correct.  The configuration I used to achieve these results is below:

**/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**

```
    # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/629def0a7a26e7c2326566f0758d4a27857b52a3/README.md#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab
    external_url 'http://mysite.example.com'

#https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#tcp-ports-for-gitlab-services-are-already-taken
    unicorn['port'] = 8081

    #https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#storing-git-data-in-an-alternative-directory
    git_data_dir "/mnt/tank/gitlab"

    #https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server
    nginx['enable'] = false
    web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
```

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
ServerName mysite.example.com

ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

# transmission
ProxyPass /transmission http://localhost:9091/transmission
ProxyPassReverse /transmission http://localhost:9091/transmission

# gitlab
ProxyPass /gitlab http://localhost:8081
ProxyPassReverse /gitlab http://localhost:8081
```

**/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml**

```
production: &base
  #
  # 1. GitLab app settings
  # ==========================

  ## GitLab settings
  gitlab:
    ## Web server settings (note: host is the FQDN, do not include http://)
    host: mysite.example.com
    port: 80
    https: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, wanting to set up gitlab with apache, but I don't know if my solution is applicable in your case:

I set up the dns record for the  subdomain 'gitlab.example.com' to point to the domain 'example.com', and added a virtualhost for the subdomain. This allowed me to have the proxy work for '/' instead of '/gitlab'. Here are my configuration files:

/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:

```
external_url 'http://localhost:81'
```

The virtualhost (in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName gitlab.example.com

    ProxyPass /  http://localhost:81
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:81
</VirtualHost>
```

This way I can use gitlab through 'http://gitlab.example.com'